# How to remove an duplicate number in a list to show a unique number instead?

Tags: c#, list, random

I've done a short program that uses a list to show 100 numbers that are unique, the rnd is from 1-100. How do I check for multiple numbers to remove them and put a unique number in it's place?

```
List<int> storage = new List<int>(); // the list

        Random random = new Random(); // the rng

        int rand = 0; // storage for the random numbers

        rand = random.Next(1, 100); // random number has now been stored into rand

        // Logic

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // this is the number of times it will loop (required 100 times)
        {
            storage.Add(i);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("List contains {0} elements", storage.Count); // This only displays the number of elements inside the list

            storage.Contains(rand); // rand has now been stored into storage

            foreach (var item in storage) // this will display the numbers in the list
            {
                Console.Write(rand + "\t");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: `storage.Contains(rand);` <-- This is incorrect - you want `storage.Add(rand);`.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this program. If the only requirement is to output a list of 100 unique integers between 1 and 100 inclusive, there is only one set of integers that meets that requirement, and it is given by `Enumerable.Range(1,100)`. Is this an assignment of some kind? What is this program supposed to demonstrate?

Comment: There are a few ways you could approach this, each with their own tradeoffs. Since you are storing all numbers between 0-99, could you initialize an array with the elements values set to their index, and then swap each element with another random index?

Comment: @JohnWu Its only to display a list that contains a 100 unique integers, that only thing that I'm missing (I assume) is how to check for duplicates and replace them with a unique one. Do I need to have more integers other than "rand" or no?

Comment: What is the allowed range for the integers? Note that currently you are using `random.Next(1, 100)` to generate random numbers in the range 1 .. 99. Note that it will never return 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashSet for this. HashSet contains only unique values.

```cs
HashSet<int> storage = new HashSet<int>(); // the set

Random random = new Random(); // the rng

int rand = 0; // storage for the random numbers

rand = random.Next(1, 101); // random number has now been stored into rand

// Logic

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // this is the number of times it will loop (required 100 times)
{
    //this code blocks generate new random number if exist in storage
    while(storage.Contains(rand)){
       rand=random.Next(1,101);
    }
    storage.Add(rand)//if value not exist it will be added to storage
}

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("List contains {0} elements", storage.Count); // This only displays the number of elements inside the list

    foreach (var item in storage) // this will display the numbers in the set
    {
       Console.Write($"{item} \t");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running that? I don't think it will ever exit the loop... The reason is that  `random.Next(1,100)` returns a random number between 1 and 99 inclusive, but you are trying to fill the collection with 100 unique integers.

Comment: Yeah you are right maybe changing rand.Next(1,101) could be better.